# TypeError: this.state.webOrders.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, display

Trying to display the api data in the pageload load in react. It worked fine if I comment the Api call and display from the testdata. Api is working fine and returning results, I was able to log the json to console. But its throwing the error `TypeError: this.state.webOrders.map is not a function` I tried searching through the forums and I added the `isLoading` flag, but didn't work.

Anybody has any suggestion or faced the similar issue please let us know. Pasted the whole component code below. I am very new to react, not sure if I am missing any core concepts and asking a dump question.

thanks,

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class WebOrderGrid extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props) //since we are extending class Table so we have to use super in order to override Component class constructor
      this.state = { //state is by default an object
        webOrders: [
         { customerAccount: 1, customerName: 'ABC', totalValue: 21, totalweight: .05,  webOrderNum: '315689' },
         { customerAccount: 2, customerName: 'TBD', totalValue: 19,  totalweight: .03, webOrderNum: '234569' },
         { customerAccount: 3, customerName: 'HHH', totalValue: 16,  totalweight: .08, webOrderNum: '11111' },
         { customerAccount: 4, customerName: 'MMMM', totalValue: 25,  totalweight: .04,webOrderNum: '8965638' }
        ],
        isLoading : true
      }
   }


   componentDidMount = () =>
   {
      console.log('componentDidMount');
     this.FetchOrders();

   }

    FetchOrders () {
      axios.get("https://localhost:44301/Orders", {
       params:{ isRefresh :false }
      }).then(result => {
        if (result.status === 200) {
         console.log('Success 200');
          this.setState({webOrders:JSON.stringify(result.data), isLoading : false });
         console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data));
      /*    this.setState({webOrders:JSON.stringify(result.data),loading:false }, function () {
            console.log('state:' + this.state.webOrders);
        }); */
        } else {
          console.log('not 200 response');
        }
      }).catch(e => {
         console.log(e.JSON);
      });
    }




      renderTableHeader() {
         let header = Object.keys(this.state.webOrders[0])
         return header.map((key, index) => {
            return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
         })
      }



renderTableData() {
   const { isLoading, webOrders } = this.state;
   return  this.props.map((order, index) => {
     const { customerAccount, customerName,  totalValue, totalweight, webOrderNum } = order //destructuring
     return (
       <tr scope="row" key={webOrderNum}>
          <td scope="col">{customerAccount}</td>
          <td scope="col">{customerName}</td>
          <td scope="col">{totalValue}</td>
          <td scope="col" >{totalweight}</td>
          <td scope="col">{webOrderNum}</td>
       </tr>
     )
  })
  

 
}



 render() {
   const { isLoading, webOrders } = this.state;

    return (
       <div>
          <h1 id='title'>webOrders</h1>
          <div className="table-responsive"> 
          {!isLoading ?
          (
          <table id='SalesOrders' className='table table-striped'>
             <tbody>
             <tr scope="row">{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
                {this.renderTableData(webOrders)}
             </tbody>
          </table>
          ): (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )
         }


          </div>
       </div>
    )
 }
}
export default WebOrderGrid;
```

Comment: `this.setState({webOrders:JSON.stringify(result.data)`, looks like `webOrders` becomes a string when you're setting it in the fetch promise success callback.

Comment: As @EmileBergeron said, you're stringifying the data you get from the API and storing that in the state. And strings don't have a `.map` function. You need to store the `webOrder` data as an array

Comment: Thankslot it worked when I remove the json.stringify

Answer (score 0):

Corrections could be seen here.

1. JSON.stringify converts your array into string. No need to stringify the result.
2. On `renderTableData`, instead of `this.props.map` use `webOrders.map`

```
 // JSON.stringify converts your array into string.
 this.setState({webOrders: result.data, isLoading : false });

renderTableData() {
   const { isLoading, webOrders } = this.state;
  // use webOrder here.
   return  webOrders.map((order, index) => {
     const { customerAccount, customerName,  totalValue, totalweight, webOrderNum } = order //destructuring
     return (
       <tr scope="row" key={webOrderNum}>
          <td scope="col">{customerAccount}</td>
          <td scope="col">{customerName}</td>
          <td scope="col">{totalValue}</td>
          <td scope="col" >{totalweight}</td>
          <td scope="col">{webOrderNum}</td>
       </tr>
     )
  })
```

Comment: Thankslot it worked when I remove the json.stringify ,  its actually webOrders.map in our code,  sorry for that